# Wait until all the callbacks have been executed and then exit

Tags: node.js

**EDIT:** This seems impossible to do because the `createWriteStream()` and other error emitters doesn't necessarily emit errors at the next tick, so this wait cannot be done. Actually, if I `shutdown()` that means that I want to finish the process immediately, so it's ok if I don't get any error.

---

```
var fs = require ("fs");
var s;

var init = function (cb){
    cb ();
};

var shutdown = function (cb){
    cb (wait);
};

var wait = function (){
    //Some kind of wait
    process.exit ();
};

init (function (){
    s = fs.createWriteStream ("?invalid").on ("error", console.error); //This emits an error
});

shutdown (function (cb){
    s.on ("close", function (error){
        if (error) console.error (error);
        cb ();
    });
    s.end ();
    cb ();
});
```

If you execute this code you won't get any error because the process is finished before the error is printed. If you change the `wait()` function to this,

```
var wait = function (){
    //Some kind of wait
    setTimeout (function (){
        process.exit ();
    }, 1000);
};
```

the error is printed and after 1s the process finishes. I want to wait to the error callback and then exit without setting a timer. I've tried with `nextTick()` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of what you're trying to achieve:

```
var fs = require ("fs");
var s;

var init = function (cb){
    cb ();
};

var shutdown = function(error){
    console.log(error);
    process.exit();
};

init(function (){

    s = fs.createWriteStream("?invalid");
    s.on("error", shutdown);
    s.on ("close", shutdown);

});
```

Comment: Just note that "?invalid" is not necessarily invalid. I had to create a file with no write permissions to get an error.

Comment: I cannot to that because the code that executes the init and shutdown functions is not mine, it's user's code. Actually, the example I posted is a simplification of my problem.